# New Relic metrics chart does not increase

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic

I added new relic to my `spring boot` aplication and I try to receive metrics count in chart, but line in chart always remains stable.
[image]

It's configuration for chart
[image]

Code

```
NewRelic.recordMetric(ForgotPasswordServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName() + "sendPassword", 1);
```

How i can make chart as see on next screenshot?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change name of metrics.

[image]

Start all custom metric names with **Custom/** (for example, **Custom/MyMetric/My_label**). The **Custom/** prefix is required for all custom metrics.

Read more about [custom metrics](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/agent-data/custom-metrics)